# Strings in Applescript depends on the system language - are there universal names?

Tags: internationalization, applescript, translation

I write some Applescripts that are gonna be deployed on machines set to different languages. I just realised that when I, for example, is waiting for an application to open a window (e.g., a Save/Open dialog) my scripts fail because on systems set to other languages these windows are not called Save or Open anymore, but rather have a translated name.

How do I handle this? Do windows have "universal base name" I can look for rather than the name I Accessibility Inspector shows? And I guess there are other strings that also are translated that I might need to access (menus, menu commands and so on) - my problem is not limited to just Open/Save dialogs.

Comment: AppleScript supports `NSLocalizedString` (`localized string`). You need to refer to and pull out the strings from the corresponding framework bundles.

Comment: @vadian Thanks, can you link to a simple example?

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppleScript supports `NSLocalizedString` (`localized string`). You need to refer to and pull out the strings from the corresponding framework bundles.

For example:

```
set finderPath to path to application "Finder"
(localized string "A16" in bundle finderPath)
```

The result is:

- in English: *You can’t undo this action.*
- in German: *Diese Aktion kann nicht widerrufen werden.*

---

`localized string` has two optional parameters:

- `from table` : The name of the strings file excluding the “.strings” suffix (default is “Localizable”)
- `in bundle` : An alias or file reference to the bundle containing the strings file (default is the current application/script bundle)

Comment: How do I know the id (A16) of a specific string? Any tool available that reveals that? And can I use A16 in Applescript to verify if a certain element is available, like <code>repeat until ((exists window "A16" of application process "iTunes"))</code>?

Comment: `A16` is the arbitrary key of the key-value pair. You have to look into in the .strings files of the bundles. Open it with a text editor providing a find function and search for the requested string. You have to write `exists window (localized string "A16" in bundle...)`

Comment: Is it possible to do it the other way around? That is "What is the string ID for the element called NN". I guess it might, in many occasions, be easier to just write a oneliner in Script Editor to get the ID than dig into a bundle with hundreds if not thousands, of strings.

Comment: No it's not, but of course you can write your own .strings file. Save the script as bundle (.scptd) and add .lproj folders. In each .lproj folder put a localized .strings file.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure I understand your last comment. Care to elaborate/rephrase?

Comment: Look into an application bundle for example iTunes. In the folder `Contents/Resources` there are many `.lproj` (localized project) folders. In each folder are .strings files which contain the localized strings. You can use this pattern also in your script. You have to save the script as script bundle (.scptd) and add the .lproj folders and the .strings files. Then you can omit the `in bundle` parameter because the own bundle is the default.