# Using Applescript to lookup key/value-pairs in XML?

Tags: xml, xpath, internationalization, applescript

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638429/strings-in-applescript-depends-on-the-system-language-are-the-universal-names) begged a follow up question.

I would like to create a short Applescript that allows me to input the name of an UI-element (the name Accessibility Inspector displays) and return the key for this element. The final purpose is to create scripts that can run on systems with different language settings.

I am not sure what a good way to achieve this would be (XPaths?) so the question is pretty open. I don't need a fancy UI or so, I just want to run it from Script Editor and am happy with manually change the name of the application/bundle I am looking at as well as the name of the element.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

XML file "strings.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<strings>
    <string id="hello">
        <token lang="en">Hello world!</token>
        <token lang="fr">Bonjour tout le monde!</token>
    </string>
    <string id="bye">
        <token lang="en">Goodbye!</token>
        <token lang="fr">Au revoir!</token>
    </string>
</strings>
```

AppleScript

```
set theKey to "bye"
set theLang to "fr"
tell application "System Events"
    tell XML file "~/Desktop/strings.xml"'s XML element "strings"
        tell (the first XML element whose id = theKey)
            set theValue to value of first XML element whose XML attribute "lang"'s value is theLang
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
log theValue
```

If you wanted to get really fancy you could use the [TMX format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_Memory_eXchange) instead of this custom XML